# How to Make Mongodb replicaset as master

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Recently because of an unknown issue our MongoDB hosted on a GCP compute VM has stopped, we were unable to restart it because it's throwing MongoDB.service is not found. so we reinstalled the MongoDB after taking a backup of all .wt files in the DB path. once we've reinstalled the MongoDB we copied the files back and we can't see the data in the DB. we tried the --repair flag but still no use.
is there a way we can get this working?

The other thing is we've taken the VM snapshot from the day before the crash. there we can see the data in MongoDB only if we run the method rs.slaveOk(). I think we can't use that DB as the primary db. is there a way that we can use this as a primary db.

I'm relatively new to the concept of replica set, Master/slave any suggestions and questions are welcome

Thanks

Comment: Was the MongoDB stopped when you take copy of .wt files? Did you copy also all other files (not just .wt)? Have a look at [Restore a Replica Set from MongoDB Backups](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/), follow it carefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the data from the snapshot with rs.slaveOk() it is easy to recover , you can reconfigure the member as standalone PRIMARY with this steps:

1. Get the current config:

   ```
   cfg = rs.conf()
   printjson(cfg)
   ```
2. Set in the temp variable cfg only the available member(in the example it is the first in the cfg with id:0 ):

   ```
   cfg.members = [cfg.members[0]]
   ```
3. Reconfigure the replicaSet only with the available member:

   ```
   rs.reconfig(cfg, {force : true})
   ```

   (Don't forget to add the {force:true} option since it is the only way to reconfigure from SECONDARY)
4. If all is good with this member and it successfully elect as PRIMARY , you can add other new members with rs.add() ...

Comment: `cfg.members[0]` is not necessarily the current node. I think `cfg.members = rs.conf().members.filter( x => x.host == db.hello().me)` is more reliable.

Comment: Indeed @Manisekhar , you need to identify which is the available member and its position in the members array so you  keep only the available member in the array ...

Comment: You may also need to run `cfg.version++`  in order to increase the version number.

Comment: Thank you @R2D2 for your help.
I've reconfigured the hostname, previously it's set the older VM host address.
now it's Elected as the Primary VM and I can see the data now

Comment: Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit for your help.
I've changed the host in rs.config(), it's Working now